# i don't understand why the array doesn't give the right answer

Tags: c#

```
char[] temparr = str;

for (int q = 0; q < temparr.Length; q++)
{
    if (q == 0) { temparr[q] = firstNewElement; }
    else { temparr[q] = str[q - 1]; }
} 
str = temparr;
```

Why is this code are setting all the `temparr` elements to `firstNewElement` variable?

Note: `str` is also an array. This is not the complete code

Comment: 'Note: Str is also an arr this is not the complete code' Well then please give us the code

Comment: What is this temparr[q] = str[q - 1]; doing?

Comment: `char[] temparr = str;` creates a second *reference* to the `str` array, not a copy. Every modification to `temparr` also modifies `str`

Answer (score 1):

When you assign

```
char[] temparr = str;
```

you are not creating a new temporary array, you are simply pointing `temparr` to `str` and then you are modifying both `str` and `temparr`.

You need to make a copy of `str`:

```
char[] temparr = (char[])str.Clone();
```

You realize you will be removing the last element of `str` with this code, correct?

A more efficient way to do the same thing would be:

```
Array.Copy(str, 0, str, 1, str.Length-1);
str[0] = firstNewElement;
```

Answer (score -1):

Because by `char[] temparr = str;`, you are copying the reference to the array. So

q=0

```
temparr[0] = firstNewElement;
```

q=1

```
temparr[1] = str[0]; // str[0] is temparr[0], temparr[0] is firstNewElement
```

Instead of `char[] temparr = str;`, consider `char[] temparr = str.Clone();` to copy the values of the array `str`.